# Test ability to query MongoDB

Tags: testing, mongodb

In a SQL database, you might run a query like `select 1` just to verify that you have a good connection to the database without needing to know anything about the contents of the database or even have permission to access anything in it.  Is there a similar sort of query I can run in MongoDB, say against a database with no collections?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in many ways :

1.Run a basic info command about the database :

```
db.stats() 
db.serverStatus()
```

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Monitoring+and+Diagnostics#MonitoringandDiagnostics-mongoShellDiagnosticCommands

2- Run a mongoDb equivalent of mysql's  'show databases' or 'show tables'

```
   'show dbs'
```

or

```
'use myDb'
'show collections'
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way it's running ping command. And it's preferred way to verify connection with the database.

Reading stats or listing dbs is a good way to do it as well, but the result can be nondeterministic (and I am not sure how it would work with different permissions).

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/ping/